# Appending a line to a file in the cat command?

Tags: command-line, pipe, cat, echo

I can do `cat file.txt` to get the contents of a file but I also want to tack on a final line of my own choosing.

I tried piping `(cat file.txt ; echo "My final line") |` but only the final line is getting passed through the pipe. How can I join the cat and final line?

Edit for a point of clarification: I do not wish to modify the file itself. I am aware that if this were the case I could do `echo "My final line" >> file.txt` or `echo "My final line" | tee -a file.txt` but I am only trying to do the append within the context of this particular command so I can pipe in the concatenation of `file.txt` and `"My final line"`.

Comment: Maybe something like `echo "My final line" >> file.txt`?

Comment: I don't want to actually append the line to the file object, just in the command / piping. I already know that I can append the line with `>>` if I wanted to edit the file itself.

Comment: Have you accidentally erased `file.txt`? Your pipe snippet should work.

Comment: @DoubleBass: Mathieu Mitchell's answer is a better one, as it doesn't modify the file (either in-memory or on disk), but instead utilizes a feature of a built-in command.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can leverage `cat`'s ability to read from stdin combined with it's ability to read multiple files to achieve this.

```
~$ cat file.txt
Hello from file.txt

~$ echo "My final line" | cat file.txt -
Hello from file.txt
My final line
```

You can also prepend a line, as such:

```
~$ echo "My final line" | cat - file.txt
My final line
Hello from file.txt
```

Note that you are not limited to a single line. `cat` will read from stdin until it reaches EOF. You can pass the output from `curl`, for example, to prepend or append to the output of `cat`.

```
~$ curl -s http://perdu.com | cat file.txt -
Hello from file.txt
<html><head><title>Vous Etes Perdu ?</title></head><body><h1>Perdu sur l'Internet ?</h1><h2>Pas de panique, on va vous aider</h2><strong><pre>    * <----- vous &ecirc;tes ici</pre></strong></body></html>
```

Comment: `(cat file.txt ; echo "My final line") | …` would also do it. But using `cat` for what it was designed for is better +1.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: Sub-shells also have the disadvantage of an additional process to fork which is relatively expensive. Try for example `echo "$$" "$BASHPID" | head -q -n 1 /proc/mounts - | cat` vs. `( head -q -n 1 /proc/mounts; echo "$$" "$BASHPID" ) | cat` or even `{ head -q -n 1 /proc/mounts; echo "$$" "$BASHPID"; } | cat`.

Answer (score 16):

For appending a line to a file, you can just use shell append redirection operator, `>>` (the file will be `open(2)`-ed with `O_APPEND` flag):

```
echo 'My final line' >>file.txt
```

---

Now, if you want just to *view* the content of the file with a final line appended, i would use `cat` with two arguments:

- First, your file obviously, let's say `file.txt`
- Second argument would be the string of your choice, and to pass the string as a filename (as `cat` only deals with files) you can leverage process substitution, `<()`, which would return a file descriptor (`/proc/self/fd/<fd_number>)`.

Putting these together:

```
cat file.txt <(echo 'My final line')
```

If you want the output to be paged, assuming `less` is your favorite pager:

```
less file.txt <(echo 'My final line')
```

Comment: `<()` works for bash, but what other shells does it work for? Ksh? Dash?

Comment: @jpaugh `ksh`, `zsh` -- Yes, `dash` -- No.

Comment: This modifies the original.

Answer (score 14):

```
sed -e '$aMy final line' file.txt
```

From `man sed` the option `-e`

```
-e script, --expression=script
    add the script to the commands to be executed
```

`$` matches the last line and  `a` appends the string.

If you wanted to permanently append the line to the file, use `-i`

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
    edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Changing the command to

```
sed -i -e '$aMy final line' file.txt
```

Comment: Use single quotes and you don't need the backslash.

Answer (score 11):

*It was already clarified in the comments to the question, but adding it again as an answer here.*

The command noted in the question,

```bash
(cat file.txt ; echo "My final line") | other command
```

works as is expected – all the output from the subshell formed by the parentheses is piped to the second command.

If the file doesn't end with a new line, the echoed string is appended to the last line – this is common with all the other solutions here, and can be solved by adding another (empty) echo before.

Comment: If the file doesn't end with a newline, I'd use `awk`: `awk 1 file.txt; echo "My final line"`. `awk 1 file` is a nice trick to compensate for missing EOL at the end of the file.

Comment: If the file doesn't end with a new line, you can also just use `echo "\nMy final line"` without having to depend on `awk`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers here but in my case I just wanted to append a newline to some stdout, by tacking a command onto the end of the pipeline. This achieves that:

```shell
$CMD_OR_COMMANDS | cat - <(echo)
```

To fit the original example:

```shell
cat file.txt | cat - <(echo "My final line")
```

Which is admittedly a verbose way of accomplishing the thing, but the key is that this pattern might fit more of your needs, since it works on anything that produces stdout.